# How to influnce into the kafka partition leader election process

Tags: apache-kafka

I am going to setup a kafka cluster for our intensive messaging system.
Currently we have setup two kafka clusters, one based in London (LD) as primary and antoher one based in New York (NY) as DR ( backup), and we have made java clients to replicate data from LD to NY.

As Kafka has built-in features such as partitioning, and replication for scalibity,  high availability and failover purpose so that we want to create a single bigger cluster comprising of both servers in London and New York

But...

We are having the problem with connectivity between NY and LD servers, the network speed is really bad.

I have performed server tests.

producer config:
- acks=1 ( requires acknowlegement from partition leader only)
- sending Async.

1. when producers in London sending messages to brokers in LD , the thoughput 100,000 msg /sec, providing message size is : 100bytes => 10MB/sec
2. when producers in London and sending message to broker in NY, the thoughput 10 msg/sec, providing message size is : 100bytes => 1KB/sec

So...

I am considering any way to make sure the producer/consumer take the advantage of locality that means if they are in the same network will send messages to the neariest broker.
Lets say: consumers in LD will send messages to LD based brokers.
(I understand that the write/read request only happens on partition leader).

Any suggestion would be highly appriciate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I understood your current structure is:

- 1 Broker located in NY.
- 1 Broker located in LD.
- n number of topics. (I am going to assume the number of topics is 1).
- n number of partitions on the topic. (I am going to assume the number of partitions is 2).
- Both of the partitions replicated over the brokers.

You want to make broker located in LD leader of all the partitions, so all the producers will interact with this broker and the broker located in NY will be used as replication. If this is the case, then, you can do the following:

Check the configuration of your topic:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --describe --topic stream-log

Topic:<topic-name>    PartitionCount:2    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
  Topic: stream-log   Partition: 0    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,1 Isr: 0,1
  Topic: stream-log   Partition: 1    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,0 Isr: 1,0
```

And assuming:

- LD Broker ID: 0
- NY Broker ID: 1

You can observe how the leader of the partition 1 is handled by the broker 1 (NY), we want to modify that, to do so is necessary to reassign the partitions:

```
./kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --reassignment-json-file manual_assign.json --execute
```

The contents of the JSON file:

```
{"partitions": [
  {"topic": "<topic-name>", "partition": 0, "replicas": [0,1]},
  {"topic": "<topic-name>", "partition": 1, "replicas": [0,1]}
 ],
 "version":1
}
```

Finally, to force kafka to update the leader, run:

```
./kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh
```

The last command will affect all the topics you have created if do not specify a list of topics, that should not be a problem but have it in mind.

Is worth to have a look to [this guide](http://blog.erdemagaoglu.com/post/128624804243/forcing-kafka-partition-leaders), it explains something similar. And if you are curious you can check the official documentation of the tools [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Replication+tools).

Comment: Thanks @jose.goncabel for your help. This is actually one of approach that we are considering,  but as far as I understand Kafka does not recommend to create a cluster cross data centers due to network connectivity, instead we should have two independent clusters, and create a mirrormaker to replicate data cross data centers.  How do  you think about this proposal?

Comment: In my opinion creating a Kafka cluster in your main data center and replicating it in another place using the mirror maker tool is a valid approach. However, you need to have in mind a few considerations, as described in the Kafka official documentation: "the mirror cluster is not really intended as a fault-tolerance mechanism (as the consumer position will be different); for that we recommend using normal in-cluster replication." You can check the documentation [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_mirror_maker).

Comment: Thank for your recommendation. Btw, I have been trying to replicate data between clusters using MirrorMaker tool. However I got folllowing error.

_italic_
[2017-02-03 06:17:00,193] FATAL [mirrormaker-thread-0] Mirror maker thread failure due to  (kafka.tools.MirrorMaker$MirrorMaker
Thread)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid timestamp -1
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord.<init>(ProducerRecord.java:60)
_italic_

Comment: I can not help you with the error, I have never used the mirroring tool. I would recommend you to open a new question with all the information about what you are trying the achieve, which command are you running and the error is showing up.