# How to force existing Kafka broker topics and partitions to be replicated to +2 new brokers added?

Tags: apache-kafka, replication

I had one Kafka broker with several topics, my topics has only one partition (partition 0), while __consumer_offsets topic has 50 partitions by default.

Then, after adding +2 new brokers and set in configs of all 3 brokers (*broker IDs are simple: 1,2,3*) the following:

1. offsets.topic.replication.factor=3
2. default.replication.factor=3
3. min.insync.replicas=2

And then set replicas to [1,2,3] in JSON file for reassign partitions per brokers, did that for all topics all partitions and even forced Leader election (as described here: [How to influnce into the kafka partition leader election process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996556/how-to-influnce-into-the-kafka-partition-leader-election-process) ) and then I see Leader everywhere "1".

Anyway I see in output of *kafka-topics --describe* script that in-sync replicas lesser than replicas set by *kafka-reassign-partitions* command at step 4 above.

Command and output is follows:

```
[appuser@broker ~]$ kafka-topics --zookeeper $KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --under-replicated-partitions --describe
        Topic: Z_player       Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 1    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 2    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 3    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 4    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 5    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 6    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 7    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 8    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 9    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 10   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 11   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 12   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 13   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 14   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 15   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 16   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 17   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 18   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 19   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 20   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 21   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 22   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 23   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 24   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 25   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 26   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 27   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 28   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 29   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 30   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 31   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 32   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 33   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 34   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 35   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 36   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 37   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 38   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 39   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 40   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 41   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 42   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 43   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 44   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 45   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 46   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 47   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 48   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: __consumer_offsets       Partition: 49   Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: account  Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
        Topic: applications     Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1
```

Yes, my own topics has only one partition number 0, which I want for safety have at all 3 brokers (or at least at 2 of 3 brokers) in case one of brokers will fail.

But as I can see, **Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1** means that topic's partition stored only on ONE broker actually :-(

How to FORCE it to be replicated **Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,2,3** or at least **Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,2** or **Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 1,3** ?

Example of well-replicated topic partitions (that ones that somehow well replicated, don't know why brokers chose them to be well replicated while anorher not):

```
[appuser@broker ~]$ kafka-topics --zookeeper $KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT --describe
Topic: X_player  TopicId: VHv3ZDRsQj26XwkB0PaONQ PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs:
        Topic: X_player  Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,1,2
Topic: X_sync    TopicId: cAYtJgZ1Qb6Xy_i4mMXlSg PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs:
        Topic: X_sync    Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,1,2
Topic: Y_player    TopicId: cDVVDAXLRL6ww1iTUi07aA PartitionCount: 1       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs:
        Topic: Y_player    Partition: 0    Leader: 1       Replicas: 1,2,3 Isr: 3,1,2
...
```

So, some existing topics are replcated, but some are not.

How to force all of them and all their partitions to be replicated (with at least 2 replicas on 2 of 3 brokers, ideally even 3 replicas on all 3 brokers) ?